# Closure default capture overhead

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Is there any overhead in using a default capture mode?

```
{
   Foo foo = ...;
   Bar bar = ...;
   [&]()
   {
       write(foo);
   }
}

{
   Foo foo = ...;
   Bar bar = ...;
   [&foo]()
   {
       write(foo);
   }
}
```

To clarify is there any cost in using the former related to bar being capture even if not used?

Comment: When you say "cost", what do you mean by that? Storage? Execution time? Compilation time? Something else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I mean if there is any run-time cost like more storage in the first case

Comment: There's no cost. Only the variables you actually *use* are captured in the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unspecified how the lambda deals with entities captured by reference, from the draft C++14 standard(`N4140`) section `5.1.2` [expr.prim.lambda]:

> An entity is captured by reference if it is implicitly or explicitly
>   captured but not captured by copy. It is unspecified whether
>   additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure
>   type for entities captured by reference. A member of an anonymous
>   union shall not be captured by reference

This wording was purposely left open to allow implementations to optimize around this, see [defect report 750:  Implementation constraints on reference-only closure objects](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#750)  which references [N2927](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2927.pdf) which says:

> The new wording no longer specifies any rewrite or closure members for
>   "by reference" capture. Uses of entities captured "by reference"
>   affect the original entities, and the mechanism to achieve this is
>   left entirely to the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

N3337 5.1.2/15 or N4527 (C++14 final draft) 5.1.2/16

> An entity is captured by reference if it is implicitly or explicitly
>   captured but not captured by copy. **It is unspecified whether
>   additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure
>   type for entities captured by reference.**

Comment: Note `N3337` is the draft closest to C++11 while `N4140` is the draft closest to C++14 which is what the OP tagged the question with. We can see from my answer the `N4140` quote is different, although the difference does not effect this question. There are many cases where the answer is different for C++11 vs C++14. While `N4527` would be the latest working draft currently available is basically C++1z.